# Rspec - Mocking an object in private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

In our application, we have written after_create/update/delete callbacks for some interested domain models. Inside of these models we create a new Audit model that xmlizes the necessary data of the changed model and store it in the Audit table. As an example, the after_create callback of Consultant model looks as below:


`def after_create

    xml = #private xmlize() is called which returns the data of new Consultant object

    audit = Audit.new :data=>xml.to_s

    audit.save

end`

Now, I would like to either mock the audit object to see if its save method is called using RSpec. Or even better, if there is a way to regex the contents of the xml through RSpec, I would be glad to learn how to do it through Ruby in Rails environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't naturally mock the Audit object because it's constructed within the method.

What you might want to do is create and inject (somwhere ...) an AuditFactory, and use that to create the Audit object.

Then the factory and the audit can both be mocked, with an expectation that the mock factory creates the mock audit, and that the audit's save method is called.

The expectation on the factory could also be set to expect the correct xml.

Comment: Having an `AuditFactory` class is probably redundant. You might like to read [an argument against such constructs in Ruby](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/15/abstractqueryfactoryfactories-and-alias_method_chain-the-ruby-way/). And you can mock the `audit` by doing this: `Audit.stub!(:new).and_return(mock(...))` and making sure the mock gets the right data and is saved.

Comment: Hadn't thought of stubbing the constructor.  Mocking in Ruby indeed works much better than Java.  This makes my answer incorrect in Ruby.  Perhaps I'll just delete it!

Comment: Thanks Don and Brian. Brian Donovan had just hit the bulls eye though ;)